# How to map DirectInput (sharpDX) device to it's corresponding HID (C#)

Tags: c#, usb, hid, sharpdx, gamepad-api

What I need is a way to find out the curresponding HID of a SharpDX.DirectInput DeviceInstance.

What I have on DirectInput side is :

```
ProductId -> 00060079-0000-0000-0000-504944564944 (always the same)
InstanceId -> 8e3d89c0-6436-11e9-8004-444553540000 (dynamic / changes every time PC starts)
```

On HID side :

```
VendorID=0x0079
ProductID=0x0006,
Version=263,
DevicePath=\\?\hid#vid_0079&pid_0006#8&1ec29a1c&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
```

I can see that the HID vendorId and ProductId are used to build the DirectInput ProductId. the problem is that I have multiple controllers connected with the same VendorId and ProductId (they are the same brand)

is there a way to do this? to know the HID devicePath of an DirectInput InstanceId?

**For context:**

I'm writing a software to automatic configure many controllers on many emulators for my custom arcade machine. The emulators use a combination of DirectInput/XInput/DSUClient (https://github.com/v1993/cemuhook-protocol). So, for each connected controller, I need to know all controllers info to be able to correctly configure each one on each emulator.

For now as a (very bad) workaround, i'm listening to inputs from DirectInput separeted from HID and when the reading occurs I know that the HID device is the DirectInput device because they occured (almost) on the same time.

I've already tried "Win32_PnPEntity" with "ManagementObjectSearcher" but had no luck

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding the solution...

```
DirectInput directInput = new DirectInput();
foreach (var deviceInstance in directInput.GetDevices())
{
    var joystick = new Joystick(directInput, deviceInstance.InstanceGuid);
    Console.WriteLine(joystick.Properties.InterfacePath)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `DIPROP_GUIDANDPATH` property that could be requested via [IDirectInputDevice8::GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee417908(v=vs.85)) API. It will return HID device path.

In SharpDX it is represented by `SharpDX.DirectInput.PropertyGuidAndPath` struct.